# Show that $G_{u,v}$ is not decidable and not recognizable (nor is its complement)

Tags: computability, turing-machines, decidability

Let $\Sigma$ be an alphabet, $u,v \in \Sigma^*, u \neq v$.

$G_{u,v} = \{ \langle M \rangle \mid M$ is turing machine, $u \in L(M) \Leftrightarrow  v \in L(M)\}$.

I understand that if it is not recognizable then its also clearly not decidable. I guess by assuming it to be recognizable one can construct some impossible machine...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One could also use Rogers's fixed point theorem ([https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kleene%27s_recursion_theorem#Rogers's_fixed-point_theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kleene%27s_recursion_theorem#Rogers%27s_fixed-point_theorem)) to prove this, although the earlier answer is more general.

Assuming for a contradiction that $G_{u,v}$ were recognizable, say by a Turing machine $M_c$, then by Church's thesis (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Church%E2%80%93Turing_thesis#Informal_usage_in_proofs), there is a recursive function $F$ such that for all $x$, $L\left(M_{F(x)}\right) = \{u\}$ if $M_c$ accepts $x$ and $L\left(M_{F(x)}\right) = \emptyset$ if $M_c$ does not accept $x$.  By Rogers's fixed point theorem, there is some $x_0$ (in fact, infinitely many such $x_0$) such that $L\left(M_{F(x_0)}\right) = L\left(M_{x_0}\right)$.

Now we get a contradiction: if $M_c$ accepts $x_0$, then $L\left(M_{x_0}\right) = \{u\}$, but this implies $u \in L\left(M_{x_0}\right)$ and $v \notin L\left(M_{x_0}\right)$, contradicting the assumption that $x_0 \in L\left(M_c\right)$.  If $M_c$ does not accept $x_0$, then $L\left(M_{x_0}\right) = \emptyset$, that is, $u \notin L\left(M_{x_0}\right)$ and $v \notin L\left(M_{x_0}\right)$, implying $x_0 \in L\left(M_c\right)$, which is again a contradiction.

Comment: Thanks for your help! We don't have Rogers theorem proved so I cannot use it unless I prove it myself, which I guess is to complicated, but I'll think about it and maybe I'll try..

Comment: As suggested by NL1992, perhaps you could use a reduction from a known recognizable but undecidable problem, such as the diagonal halting problem $K = \{e: M_e~\mbox{accepts $e$}\}$.  Here are the details: by Church's thesis, there is a recursive function $f$ such that for all $e$, $L(M_{f(e)}) = \{u\}$ if $e \in K$ and $L(M_{f(e)}) = \emptyset$ if $e \notin K$; so $e \notin K \Leftrightarrow f(e) \in G_{u,v}$, and thus $G_{u,v}$ is not recognizable.  To show complement of $G_{u,v}$ is not recognizable: in the earlier construction, replace $\{u\}$ by $\{u,v \}$, $\emptyset$ by $\{u\}$.

Answer (score 1):

Using Rice's theorem you may claim that it is not recognizable (as any machine accepting the empty set is in the language and this is a 'semantic' language, determined only by the languages of the Turing machines involved).
For the other direction, to show that its complement is not recognizable, you can show a reduction from $A_{TM}$ to this language, that is,
$$f(<M,w>)=N$$
such that on input $x\neq u$, $N$ accepts, and on input $u$, $N$ simulates the run of $M$ on $w$ and answers according to that run.

Comment: Thanks for your help! Unfortunately we have proved only some form of rice theorem where we show certain languages are undecidable (not unrecognizable)..I guess I have to use somehow that the equivalence of turing machines is not recognizable..

Comment: You can show a similar reduction to show it is not recognizable (from $A_{TM}$ to the complement of the language mentioned above)